# Discord.js not logging in

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I cannot figure out why my bot is not working. Can someone please tell me why it is not logging in?? It shows the logo (the last console.log line), but does not say, "logged in as foo#1234". (I am not getting any errors as well.)

```
code removed because of answered question. the code worked fine ;)
```

Comment: If your console.log inside the ready event executes than your bot is logging in successfully. What may make you think it's still offline?

Comment: The OP is saying that the `console.log` in the last line of the code is working but the `client.on('ready')` function is not firing

Comment: I see now, thanks. In that case @bmp how are you starting the node process?

Comment: @bmp, can you also check if the the token in your code is the correct one for the bot? At some point in time, you might have regenerated your token and so you might still be using the old token

Comment: @Elitezen In the discord server, it is offline

Comment: @Caladan so do I need to move the logo function towards the beginning? Before, it was working perfectly fine as is

Comment: Have you changed your bot token recently?

Comment: @Caladan Not that I know of, when I get home I will make a new bot token and change it in the script

Comment: Other than the token thing, I really don't see any problem with your code. It should theoretically run. If the token is not wrong and it is the correct one, then I am not sure about what you will need to do

Comment: You start the node app in a Discord server? Try running it directly through the command line with `node .` or using nodemon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `client.once(‘ready’, async () => {//code here});` as a a pose to `client.on()`

Comment: I can’t try that right now, but I will when I get home. Thanks

Comment: Do I necessarily need code inside of the function, or no

Comment: Using `on` or `once` will only change how many times the listener is fired for that event

Comment: @Elitezen it was the token

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on [discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/), here's the base code to get you started:

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

Open your terminal and run `node index.js` (assuming that your file name is index.js) to start the process. If you see "Ready!" after a few seconds, you're good to go!

I recommend for you to follow [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin), it helped me a lot with the first steps with the discord bot.

Comment: That was not my problem

Answer (score 0):

The Token had reset for some reason, I do not remember resetting it, but after updating the token, it worked fine. Thank you for your answers and helpful comments.
**If somebody else is having this problem, try resetting the token again.**